# Create an update column for alert system in SQL-server/SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I wish to create an online alert system in SSRS visual studio. meaning I have 2 online SQL queries that gives me online data about people present:

TABLE 1 example: People waiting for X more then 8 hours:

```
  Name         Waiting_Time
 ------------------------------
 Brian             08:45
```

TABLE 2 example: People waiting for Y more then 4 hours:

```
  Name          Waiting_Time
  ------------------------------------
 Danielle          04:23
 Ari               06:56
```

I've created an SSRS report that shows both tables and their waiting time online at the moment the report is opened.

What I want is to create an alert for every **NEW** row enters one of the tables.  how can I do it? I thought maybe SQL-wise by entering an ETL DATE/ a date of which the row entered the table (How can I do it? - in SQL) and then create an alert every 15 min for all values with ETL\a date of which the row entered the table (update date) new from the past 15 min.. how can I do it on SQL?? please help with that...

desirable output:

```
  Name         Waiting_Time          Enter_Date  (the time key in which he entered the table)
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 Brian             08:45           2023-01-29 22:46
```

maybe theres an other way?

would love for some advise and help!